# Sort the correlation matrix based on the last column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, matrix, correlation

I want to plot the correlation for `df` and then sort all the parameters based on the **last** column/row of the sorted matrix. I wasn't able to sort `by` using the `pd.sort_values()`.

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

# Locate and load the data file
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/suicide_rates.csv')

# Sorted correlation matrix
corr = df.corr().abs()
s = corr.unstack()
so = s.sort_values(by=df[-1], kind="mergesort")
print(so)
```

Traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod3.py", line 15, in
>
> so = s.sort_values(by=["generation"], kind="mergesort") TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(df.head().tostring(index=False))`, please.

Comment: It seems you've unstacked into a `Series`. Which means that there is no longer a `by` argument. Difference between [Series.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: Instead of `suicide_rates.csv`, could you please create a reproducible example. It doesn't need to be big. Just 3x3 should suffice.